# Shell script to run a series of commands (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, automation, command

I'm new to Ubuntu and command line scripts and wondering how to write a script that runs / automates a series of steps. For example, a script that does the below steps. I could save it as "doeverything.sh" and put it in my user root.

1. sudo -s in & enter password
2. cd into /x/y/z directory
3. run ./script1.sh
4. wait until done
5. run ./script2.sh
6. wait until done
7. npm start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try this

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /x/y/z
bash ./script1.sh #Should run synchronously, won't continue until script1 is finished 
bash ./script2.sh
npm start
```

Make sure you `chmod +x doeverything.sh`
Then run it with `./doeverything.sh`

Comment: the cd and sudo -s + password are working... but it doesn't seem to run the two scripts. (bash lines). It roots me into the right directory and stops.

Comment: May not need the `./` before the script name, granted they do exist in the directory.

Comment: I also have a sudo -s / password lines at the beginning and it roots in but stops before running the cd command.

Comment: Ah I see, are you trying to embed the password into the script, or prompt the user?